# rational parameterization of a plane curve

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

Say one has a plane curve defined by a polynomial equation
$$P(x,y)=0$$
and one knows that the curve has genus 0. Is there an implementation in Mathematica of a (proper) rational parameterization, i.e., a function that computes a pair of rational functions $(x(t), y(t))$ generically one-to-one solving the equation above?
e.g., for
$$P(x,y)=1+x^2 y^2-x^3 y^2$$
the answer should be (up to Mobius transformations)
$$x(t)=1+t^2,\qquad y(t)=\frac{1}{t(1+t^2)}$$

Comment: [Michal Bizzarri & Miroslav Lávička (2009)](https://doi.org/10.1080/09720502.2009.10700627) has a *Mathematica* implementation for computing rational parametrizations.

Comment: Yes, I saw this, but the link to their code is broken, AFAICT. Unless you happen to know an alternative link..

Comment: @PaulZinn-Justin Did you try writing the (corresponding) author of that paper? See https://www.zcu.cz/en/about/people/staff.html?osoba=11521

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution

```
Solve[1 + x^2*y^2 - x^3*y^2 == 0, y]

Out[]= {{y -> -(1/Sqrt[-x^2 + x^3])}, {y -> 1/Sqrt[-x^2 + x^3]}}

 % /. x -> 1 + t^2 // FullSimplify

Out[]= {{y -> -(1/Sqrt[(t + t^3)^2])}, {y -> 1/Sqrt[(t + t^3)^2]}}
```

In the general case, we solve the equation and make the substitution

```
Solve[P[x,y]==0,y]
%/.x->f[t]//FullSimplify
```

The problem of parametrization does not have a unique solution; therefore, the question of choosing a function `f[t]` remains open. If the equation `P[x,y]==0` is not explicitly solved for `x` or `y`, then the question of parameterization remains open.

Comment: to clarify, the input is the polynomial, the output is the rational parameterization. the latter is not known a priori.

Comment: See update of my answer.

Comment: That is not a rational parametrization (it has fractional exponents).

Comment: I think your answer basically ends at the start of the OPs question: Is there a function (that tries) to find a possible $f(t)$ yielding a rational parametrization (if it exists)?